# how to remove custom scrolling set forth in this codepen mobile example

Tags: jquery, css, iphone, mobile, canvas

I found this really great codepen! There's one thing I'd like to change, the scroll speed when you view this thing on the iPhone. It doesn't scroll at the normal speed. You kind of have to inch your way through the site. Here's a [URL](http://blastercorp.com/mobile/alt2/) for you to view on an iPhone to see what I mean. The scrolling only gets weird when you view that link on an iPhone. On a desktop it seems to behave normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try applying the following style rules on scrollable element for smooth scrolling in iOS devices.

```
overflow: scroll
-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
```

read more @ csstricks: [momentum scrolling on ios overflow elements](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/momentum-scrolling-on-ios-overflow-elements/)